# How to inject javascript in the default browser React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to make a post form in react native in the default browser. Firstly I go to the url in the browser with:

```
 Linking.canOpenURL(this.state.videoCallUri)
  .then((supported) => {
    if (supported) {
      Linking.openURL(this.state.videoCallUri);
    }
  })
```

[image]

After the page is open in the default I want to make an automatic request for completing the login with this post form:

```
<html>
 <body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
  <form action=${this.state.videoCallUri} method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="target" value="marian" />
    <input type="hidden" name="requestOrigin" value="marian" />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value=${this.props.username} />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value=${this.props.password} />
    <input type="hidden" name="eventID" value=${
      this.props.countryCode + "-" + this.props.fiscalCode
    } />
  </form>
</body>
```

Do you have any idea how to make this post form automatic after the login page is open in the browser? Is any possible way?

I want to mention that I don't to use webview.

Best Regards

Comment: If you are able to change website code then you could use query params.

Open url from RN app: yourwebsite?videoCallUri=abcdef&countryCode=xx&fiscalCode=yy

and then inside your website (if it's react check this url: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) use these params to pre-fill values on the website.

Not sure about passing a password in query string is a good idea, encrypt it.

Comment: @latovic no I am not able to change website code moreover it is developed in vue. Do you have any other idea how to do?